# Mongoose: How to get the past 7 days upload data statistics from DB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In the User Document, I have registered users. I want to show the last 7 days' stats through API. 1st say- 7 users, 2nd  day- 5 users, 3rd day- 3 users......
UserSchema contain- name, email, createdAt etc. How can I do that in Mongodb/mongoose?

sample data:

```
    {
        "_id": "612fa439ddb04331d6ea1e5d",
        "name": "imran-1630512185253",
        "createdAt": "2021-09-01T16:03:05.266Z",
    },
     {
        "_id": "612fa439ddb04331d6ea1e5d",
        "name": "imran-1630512185253",
        "createdAt": "2021-08-31T16:03:05.266Z",
    },
    ...........
```

expected output :

```
    "filterData" : {
        1st day: 3,
        2nd day: 5,
        3rd day: 3,
        4th day: 8,
        ...
     }
```

Use this API, I want to create a chart to show statistics. that API should provide which day, how many users were created.

Comment: provide sample data , and sample of your expected output

Comment: Updated, can you check again?

Comment: 7 days from today or last 7 days?

Comment: past 7 days from today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you are describing is grouping a series of documents by day, when those documents contain UTC datetime.

MongoDB internally stores dates/times as the number of milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970, so the first step will need to be calculating the start-of-day for each document, then group by that start-of-day value.

If you are using MongoDB 5.0 you can use the [$dateTrunc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateTrunc/) operator:

```
{$dateTrunc:{date:"$createdAt",unit:"day",timezone:"America/New_York"}}
```

For older versions, you can either calculate the date object that represents the start of day or build a string containing just the date.

For the string option:

```
{$concat: [
   {$toString:{$year:{ date:"$createdAt", timezone:"America/New_York" }}},
   "-",
   {$toString:{$month:{ date:"$createdAt", timezone:"America/New_York" }}},
   "-",
   {$toString:{$dayOfMonth:{ date:"$createdAt", timezone:"America/New_York" }}},
]}
```

So overall the aggregation pipeline would be:

- $match to select documents in the desired timeframe
- $project to calculate the start of day for each document
- $group by the start of day, counting the number of occurrences
- further stages to convert the document into the desired format

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate()-7);
```

then

```
users.find({"createdAt": { $gt: d }})
```

Comment: use this API, I want to create a chart to show statistics. that should provide which day, how many users were created.