# Mongoose: How many users were created for every day

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to count how many users were created every day last week. I can get a total created user number of last week

```
    var d = new Date();
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - 7);

    const data = await User.count({ "createdAt": { $gt: d } })
    return res.status(200).json({ error: false, data: data })
```

sample data:

```
{
    "_id": "612fa439gdb04331d6ea1e5d",
    "name": "imran",
    "createdAt": "2021-09-01T16:03:05.266Z",
},
 {
    "_id": "612fa439ddb44331d6ea1e5d",
    "name": "Hossain",
    "createdAt": "2021-08-31T16:03:05.266Z",
},
...........
```

expected output :

```
"user_count" : {
    02-09-2021: 3,
    01-09-2021: 5,
    31-08-2021: 3,
    30-08-2021: 5,
    ...
 }
```

Use this API, I want to create a chart to show statistics. that API should provide which day, how many users were created. How can I do that?

Comment: Is this question significantly different than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69034831/mongoose-how-to-get-the-past-7-days-upload-data-statistics-from-db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this through mongodb, you can try converting your `createdAt` field to an actual date and then group by this date after formatting it to `yyyy-mm-dd`. Something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      createdAtDate: {
        $toDate: "$createdAt"
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $dateToString: {
          format: "%Y-%m-%d",
          date: "$createdAtDate"
        }
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      count: 1,
      date: "$_id",
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Here's an example on mongoplayground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/8D9-kHZmPTo

Comment: In Mongo 5.0 you can also use `{ $count: { } }` instead of `{$sum: 1}`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: Yep, that's correct. Gotta get used to Mongo 5 still ;)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should create a new object like this:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 7);

const data = await User.find({ "createdAt": { $gt: d } })
var userData = {};

data.forEach((user) => {
    const createdAt = user.createdAt.split("T")[0];
    const count = userData[createdAt] ? userData[createdAt] : 0;
    userData[createdAt] = count + 1;
})

console.log(userData)
```